# Tapping on time in WKWebView triggers Calendar iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios-universal-links

I am using WKWebView to load an appointment scheduling page from a URL, which displays times lots. When user taps on the appointment slot, that action opens iOS Calendar app.
The links to the times lots do not contain any universal links that appear like calendar links, so it seems like iOS is doing some weird nonsense.
This issue occurs on both real device and the simulator, running iOS 16.1

Here is a video screenshot of what happens: [LINK](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CRHbAaxjGzsfsIPyBhdxuLgI0Q3m61HY/view?usp=sharing)

ViewController responsible for appointment scheduling:

```
    class AppointmentVC: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    
    var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        
        webView.customUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.95 Safari/537.36"
        webView.allowsLinkPreview = false
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
        

        
        activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
        activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
        activityIndicator.style = UIActivityIndicatorView.Style.gray
        view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
        activityIndicator.startAnimating()

        let url: URL = URL(string: "https://...")!
        let urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView.load(urlRequest)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

}
```

This is not the expected behavior and I tried random things like changing user agent, disabling link previews, but nothing seems to work and I have no clue where to even begin. Is there a way to block an app from opening any other apps completely?

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove Calendar Events from Data Detection types: uncheck this flag:

[image]